# How to add incrementing numbers to a username that is already taken

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am trying to write a script that creates usernames from a file, but if there are two usernames that are the same it will increment the latter username by 1 each time. I think where I am messing up is the if/else statement, but any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 < file" exit 1
fi

while read user_list; do
    first=echo $user_list | cut -f 1 -d ',' `last=`echo $user_list | cut -f 2 -d ','
    lastl=echo $last | head -c 1 usern=echo $first $lastl | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'
    tname=echo $first $last 
    groupadd $usern useradd -c "${first}${last}" -d /home/${usern} -g $usern -m -s /bin/bash $usern
    passwd=$(cat /dev/urandom |tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9' | head -c 8)
    cat /tmp/pw.tmp | /usr/bin/passwd --stdin ${usern} > /dev/null
    echo "adding $tname : $usern, $passwd"
done

original_username=$usern
username_digit=0

while read line; do
    grep -w $usern /etc/passwd
    if [[ ! usern /etc/passwd]]; then
        username_digit=$((username_digit +1))
        usern=$((original_username + $username_digit))
    else
        usern+$original_username
    fi
done
```

Comment: Can you expand with a _short_ list of usernames you would like to use; what you would like the output to be; and what the output actually is?

Comment: -1 This script is a mess, really... It's like imaginary code. And the answer is not well explained/formated.

Comment: 1. Backticks don't nest. Use `$()` which does. 2. `first=echo ...` is meaningless as is. 3. Useless use of `cat` in all places. Use `cmd < file` instead of `cat file|cmd`. 4. Get a good book on shell scripting and read your shell man page :-)

Comment: @floris For example, the name Jet Black is in the text file. The output should look like `adding Jet Black, jetb, (Random Password).` and it outputs that perfectly so I know the top half works fine. But if I had another user in the file named Jet Brown, the username would still want to be jetb, but since it is already taken it would have to add a number, so it would be jetb1. And if more jetb usernames come up it would have to be jetb2, jetb3, etc.  Sorry for the bad code, I've only started learning a few weeks ago..

Answer (score 0):

```
if grep -q "^${usern}:" /etc/passwd; then
    username_digit=$((username_digit++))
    usern="$original_username$username_digit"
(...)
```

Comment: What happens when `$usern` matches other fields in `/etc/passwd` like root's home directory or login shell? You should anchor the search more specifically.